# Adding jQuery div that flashes up and then disappears

Tags: jquery, html

Adding content of user's input into a new div as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="mform">
<form> 
    <textarea rows="3" cols="48" id="message">Leave a message here</textarea> 
    <input class="post" type="submit" value="Post">
</form> 
</div>      

<div id="mboard">

</div>
```

With a supporting jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$(".post").click(function () {
    posted = $("#message").val();
    jQuery("<div/>", {
        id: "msg",
        css: {opacity:1.0}, 
        text: posted,
        }).prependTo("#mboard");
        console.log("here");
});

})
```

It seems to go through ok and the content flashes up in the new div for a second but then disappears. The same thing happens with my console.log's as well.

I've specified the opacity so that once this is working I can set it to 0 and then add an .animate to fade up the content once it's posted.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that your input button is a submit button, so is submitting the form back to itself, which means the page is reloaded.

Change your js to this:

```
$(".post").click(function (e) {
    posted = $("#message").val();
    jQuery("<div/>", {
        id: "msg",
        css: {opacity:1.0}, 
        text: posted,
        }).prependTo("#mboard");
        console.log("here");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note the addition of a parameter `e` (representing the event) to the click handler, and the call to `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/RmSZz/

Answer (score 1):

it's because you perform a **submit** request and then reload the whole page. if you want to cancel the submit request add `return false;`